# Print lines after a pattern match until next pattern match Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file like this

```
ababaabababab
+hostname R1
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 +shutdown
+banner login
-hostname r
ababababababa
ababaabababab
r#
```

I would like to get something like this output

```
>>> print running_conf

+hostname R1
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 +shutdown
+banner login



>>> print saved_conf     
-hostname r
ababababababa
ababaabababab
```

After trying so many stuff on this site, I still can't make it work. this is my code

```
with open ("file.text", "r") as saveoutput:
    for line in saveoutput:
        if line.startswith( '+' ):
            continue
            if line.startswith( '-' ):
                break
        print line
    for line in saveoutput:
        if line.startswith( '-' ):
            if line.endswith( '#' ):
                break
        print line
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will output everything in your file from a line starting with '+' onwards till a line starting with "-" gets reached:

```
copy = False

with open ("file.text", "r") as saveoutput:
    for line in saveoutput:
        if line.startswith( '+' ):
            copy = True
        if line.startswith( '-' ):
            copy = False
        if copy:
            print line
```

and the following program

```
copy = False

with open ("file.text", "r") as saveoutput:
    for line in saveoutput:
        if line.startswith( '-' ):
            copy = True
        if line.endswith( '#' ):
            copy = False
        if copy:
            print line
```

will output everything from the first line starting with a "-" till the line ending with a "#". In case you want to have a single program that is doing both actions altogether:

```
copy1 = False
copy2 = False

with open ("file.text", "r") as saveoutput:
    for line in saveoutput:
        if line.startswith( '+' ):
            copy1 = True
        if line.startswith( '-' ):
            copy1 = False
        if line.startswith( '-' ):
            copy2 = True
        if line.endswith( '#' ):
            copy2 = False
        if copy1 or copy2:
            print line
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the program that gives your desired output, although please specify the cases of your output clearly.

```
flag=False
with open ("file.txt", "r") as saveoutput:
    for line in saveoutput:
        if line.startswith('-'):
            flag=False
        elif line.startswith('+'):
            flag=True
        if flag:
            print(line,end='')

print('------------------------')
flag=False
with open ("file.txt", "r") as saveoutput:
    for line in saveoutput:
        if (line.startswith('+')) or (line.endswith('#\n')):
            flag=False
        elif line.startswith('-'):
            flag=True
        if flag:
            print(line,end='')
```